# OAAM 11gR2 Authentication Issue - OTP screen not presented for 2 factor users

Tags: oim

I'm using **Oracle 11gR2 OAM-OAAM** integrated environment.

**Test Case for 2 factor user**:

1. Access Protected URL.
2. Once Login page is presented, enter username and password.
3. After successful authetication, instead of redirecting to OTP page, its redirecting back to Login page with error - Invalid Username or Password.
   It's not the issue with credentials because if I change the factor to 1 and use the same credentials, authentication is successful and user is redirected to home page.

**Note** - Its same behaviour for all the 2 factor users.

This issue is in 2 environments only:

1. Environment 1 - It was working fine from last 3 years until last week.
2. Environment 2 - It was never working from the beginning.

But its working fine in other 4 environments.

**What I have done until now:**

Compare OAAM configuration and properties with other working environments.
**Result** - It's the same

**Analysis:** I have checked OAAM Admin console session details, below is triggered:

***Policy*** - OAAM Challenge Policy

***Rule*** - Questions Active

***Rule notes*** - User failed to answer question more than specified number of times.

But all the users have questions registered in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this particular user account is locked out from OTP.

Verify the value of the OTP failure counter as follows:
In OAAM console > Session tab > Click on user > Summary > Profile Data > Failure Counter Data > OTP Challenge, Failure Count = 4 (for example)

To unlock / reset the counter: 
In OAAM console > Session > Link to Case > Create New Case > Customer resets > User Item = Unlock OTP

Comment: Hi, there was no issue with Failure counts - OTP or Questions. This issue was solved by disabling Questions Active rule.